# Different file extensions for different versions

Tags: ruby, carrierwave

I am using carrierwave to upload images. I need my main image version
to remain in its original format, but other versions to be converted
to gif.

At the moment i am doing something like this:

```
 def filename
   change_ext_to_gif(super)
 end

 def change_ext_to_gif(ext)
   ext.chomp(File.extname(ext)) + ".gif"
 end

 version :preview do
   process :resize_to_fill => [60, 60]
   process :convert => "gif"
 end

 version :full do
   process :resize_to_limit => [320, 320]
   process :convert => "gif"
 end

 version :mobile do
   process :resize_to_limit => [72, 96]
   process :convert => "gif"
 end
```

Of course, this changes extension of my original file as well. Is
there any way to solve this? I guess i need to override some methods
in the version's blocks. But i was not able to figure out them (I
tried overriding filename and url this helps but prevents version`s
files from being deleted).

Answer (score 6):

You can ovvierde the filename that gets used per version like so:

```
 version :mobile do
   process :resize_to_limit => [72, 96]
   process :convert => "gif"
   def full_filename(for_file = model.logo.file)
     "fiename here"
   end
 end
```

So just leave the original filename as you'd like and then alter it per version. There are further examples on the wiki here:

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-To%3A-Move-version-name-to-end-of-filename%2C-instead-of-front